# how to get scalebar in bingmap

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

how to get  scalebar value using javascript in Bingmap REST API, has shown in below image?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Bing Maps REST imagery service doesn't have an option to add a scale bar. If you know the zoom level and center point, you could add one with a drawing tool library. You can find some logic on how to create a scale bar based on zoom level and center point here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-maps-scale-bar-control